# MKMapViewでマップアプリを作成していますが、ボタンでマップを回転させる部分がわかりません。

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

タイトルの通りMKMapでマップアプリを作成しておりますが、どうしてもボタンでマップを回転させる必要があり、そこの部分が分からず大変困っております。試してみたコードを載せますので、宜しくお願い致します。

```
    let maxWidth: CGFloat = self.view.bounds.width
    let maxHeight: CGFloat = self.view.bounds.height

    myMapView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 70, width: maxWidth, height: maxHeight - 20.0 - 50.0)
    let angle : CGFloat = CGFloat((30.0 * Double.pi) / 180.0)
    myMapView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
    self.view.addSubview(myMapView)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myMapView.camera.heading += 10
```

でできました